# How to do feature engineering on anonymous dataset?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I have a task to perform classification on a data set in which the feature names are anonymous like var1,var2 etc. There is mixed continuous and one hot encoded features. I am bit stuck how to make new features out of the existing features and perform EDA on it.

Comment: I think your question is better suited for Cross-Validated (stats.stackexchange.com). Could you perhaps clarify (a) what you mean by _make new features out of the existing features_? Do you mean that you're not sure how to encode the columns as features? (b) what you mean by _EDA_ (is it _Exploratory Data Analysis_)?

Comment: New features I mean feature generation out of the given features and yes EDA is Exploratory Data Analysis

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches to feature engineering, which could be also used on anonymized data:

- transformation of continuous variables: log, power, normalization;
- aggregations: `df.groupby(['cat_column']).agg({'continuous_column': ['min', 'max', 'mean', 'std'])
- interactions of continuous variables: addition, subtraction, multiplications, division
  And so on.